# Why do I get a rank deficiency in the QDA

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-analysis

I am working on the titanic titanic dataset from Kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data) and I'm trying to apply various models to that dataset.

Before doing so I've done the following modifications on the dataset:

```
df.train <- dplyr::select(df.train,-PassengerId,-Name,-Ticket,-Cabin)
df.train$Survived <- factor(df.train$Survived)
df.train$Pclass <- factor(df.train$Pclass)
df.train$Parch <- factor(df.train$Parch)
df.train$SibSp <- factor(df.train$SibSp)
```

I've also set the age and we are in a situation where

> anyNA(df.train) == F

So when I do a logistic regression, and a LDA everything works fine (even if surprisingly they provide exactly the same result), but when I try:

```
qda.model <- qda(Survived~. , data = df.train)
```

I get :

> Error in qda.default(x, grouping, ...) : groupe 0 n'est pas de rang plein

From what I understand it means that I have a rank deficiency.

Some researches online lead me to here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it

But I really don't see what is wrong with the data, I have 8 predictors and 891 observations, no predictor seem to be a linear combination of others..

Can you please explain me what goes wrong with this QDA?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: QDA does not work with factors (https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-July/137215.html) maybe that is what's causing the issue.